# MongoDB error with Mongoid, Heroku, Device, MongoHQ and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, device, mongohq, mongoid3

I'm working on [a simple app](http://bookfoo.herokuapp.com/) that is currently deployed to heroku now - it is using mongoid, device and can create user login very easily in localhost, but not in production at heroku. You can try to create an account, and it gives an error after submit.

I think my mongoid.yml for production needs to change, but I have no idea how.

My `heroku config` has the following:

```
 === Config Vars for bookfoo
DATABASE_URL:        postgres://jeibucpexp:bVZzGaGPUeGylwmA7dyE@ec2-107-20-186-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com/jeibucpexp
GEM_PATH:            vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG:                en_US.UTF-8
MONGOHQ_URL:         mongodb://heroku:14bc6d476e6449c952d6350b07e89643@alex.mongohq.com:10065/app6153931
MONGOLAB_URI:        mongodb://heroku_app6153931:og03dk0hdrj7r8lsit51k6ah9n@ds037097-a.mongolab.com:37097/heroku_app6153931
PATH:                bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
RACK_ENV:            production
RAILS_ENV:           production
SHARED_DATABASE_URL: postgres://jeibucpexp:bVZzGaGPUeGylwmA7dyE@ec2-107-20-186-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com/jeibucpexp
```

mongoid.yml has the following as suggested in heroku:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: bookfoo_app_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: bookfoo_app_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
    options:
      skip_version_check: true
      safe: true
```

my gemfile has the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'mongoid-rspec'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'email_spec'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'launchy'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "mongoid", :git => "git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git"
gem "bson_ext"
gem "devise"
```

after `git push heroku master` it gives me the following hints:

```
There is a configuration error with the current mongoid.yml.
       Problem:
       No database provided for session configuration: :options.
       Summary:
       Each session configuration must provide a database so Mongoid knows where the default database to persist to. What was provided was: {"skip_version_check"=>true, "safe"=>true}.
       Resolution:
       If configuring via a mongoid.yml, ensure that within your :options section a :database value for the session's default database is defined.
       Example:
       \_\_development:
       \_\_\_\_sessions:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_options:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_database: my_app_db
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_hosts:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_- localhost:27017
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mongoid.yml should be so (my indentation was wrong):

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

Comment: thanks for this. I was looking for hours already and then I realised it was indentation :/